# How to blame bad luck?

Tags: word-request, expressions, sentence-request

What is the fixed expression which can be said by an unlucky person to show their disappointment after a bad outcome / happening in English?

In Russian people have the slang: "**ёлки-палки**" which is a curse that is normally used when one wishes to express their vexation. 
I know there are dozens of ways to show you don't like something that is going on like: "Oh my god / gosh / goodness / lord" or simply in a ruder way: "damn", "shit" or "fuck"!
But But I am looking for an informal, (not rude) expression which blames the **bad luck of the person**!

I found the expressions:

> Some luck! 
>   What luck! 
>   Tough luck!  
>   Bad luck!  
>   Rotten luck!

in some translation pages, but either I cannot find a reliable source to make sure if they mean what I need or I don't find them similar to my needed expression.

Like [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/tough-luck) says:

Tough Luck
(British English) -> used when you feel sympathy about something bad that has happened to someone:

- You didn’t get the job? Oh, tough luck!

I am wondering whether there is an expression you could suggest?

Comment: Are you looking for something the unlucky person would say, or that would be said by another person to the unlucky person?

Comment: Corrected British English: "You didn't get the job? Ah, bollocks mate, sorry."

Comment: If you have a few potential phrases that might mean something, you could use Google to narrow it down. You could search for each term (especially in quotes) to see what results you get and how many of them you get, although Some Luck is a novel, which may skew the results a bit. You could also add "definition" to the search to see whether there's a definition (and also how many results that returns). In this case I get nothing useful for "some luck" and "what luck", but for the others I get the same definition, which also tells me those terms are used interchangeably.

Comment: I hesitated to post an answer since it's unclear for me which person will say it, but I feel "How unfortunate!", "Poor you...", and "What a pity!" might express a similar feeling.

Comment: @Muzer I am seeking an expression that the unlucky person utters to blame his/her bad luck.

Comment: @Andrew T. I edited my question.

Comment: It might help monolingual English speakers trying to answer your question if you could say a little more about the Russian expression you are using as a basis of comparison. A transliteration into the Roman alphabet would let us know how it sounds and might help us think of a word with a similar origin in English. Also, do the words have literal meanings but are being used in a slangy way? Maybe you could give a literal translation.

Comment: Well @Mark Foskey; It literally means "firs(trees) and sticks." Actually елки зеленые is reckoned to be the original form, and елки-палки - its jocular alteration. It is used by younger people and those who want to underline their casual manner of beheaviour. It can be used in any non-formal situation with friend.

Comment: Any of your examples would work except for "What luck!", which to me could imply *good* luck, although I suppose it depends on your inflection.  I wouldn't use it in writing because it might be misconstrued.

Comment: Thank you &Darrel Hoffman. Just may I ask you whether you are an American. Meanwhile, can the **"unlucky person use these all regarding himself / herself?"**

Comment: If you're really seeking something that might be said by an unlucky person then none of those examples would be appropriate… they would only ever be said by someone other than the unlucky one.

The unlucky person might well say "Just my luck!" but none of the other phrases would be appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The person who didn't get the job might say:

> That's *just* my luck.

An observer might say:

> Sorry; that's so unlucky.

Comment: I know the expression "Just my luck" and that is a good one. But I need to find another expression which is said to show one's anger (not in a impolite way) and not directly blaming the "luck" itself. Exactly as the Russian term "ёлки-палки" does.

Comment: @A-friend Though I'm unfamiliar with Russian, in my opinion that phrase is exactly what you want. It's usually stated kind of sarcastically, with a sense of frustrated defeat. Alternative: "_Typical!_" Note the emphasis.

Comment: @A-friend you will almost certainly never find an answer, the less so since sadly, you changed the criteria from blaming or being disappointed to expressing anger…

Seriously, nothing on this page up to and including 00:07:00 200515 could near close to "Just my luck."

That is the closest English phrases get to your specification and nothing else here has been worth thinking about.

Do you want to drop the idea that the expression must come from the victim and allow an observer to say it?

Answer (score 5):

The problem with trying to answer a question like this is that informal English has literally hundreds, possibly thousands, of ways to express sympathy for a bad outcome by blaming it on a pattern of bad outcomes due to chance. This is made worse because (a) such informal phrases change relativly rapidly, and (b) they frequently employ irony to say one thing literally while meaning the opposite.

> You always have all the luck, don't you?

is an example where the meaning is

> You never have any luck, do you?

"Tough luck" and "bad luck" are probably the most common choices that avoid a hint of irony.

Comment: Hi Jeff and thank you for the answer. Just may I ask you for which dialect are you speaking?

Comment: In my experience (BrEng) at least, using "Tough Luck" is generally more negative. I wouldn't say it if you lose a hand of poker, I'd use it if I'm telling you to go to hell. e.g. If I'm closing the shop and you say "But I wanted to buy X", "Tough Luck!"

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix I reckon you're right, but I'd say the original meaning works too; it all depends on your tone of voice. However more generally, I think what OP and this post have missed, at least if I interpreted the question correctly, is that all of these are said by *other people* to the unlucky one, whereas OP is looking for something a person would say themselves if they are unlucky.

Comment: @A-friend I speak American English in what would formerly have been known as the received version.

Comment: @Muzer If the OP was looking for a self-referential phrase, it would have been much harder to miss that meaning had the example not been addressed to "you."

Comment: @Jeff Morrow but I guess I had to be more clear when I wrote my question. As you are well aware, "tough al/ bad luck etc." are used when you feel sympathy about something bad that has happened to "**someone else**" while I need something that the unlucky person uses to blame **his / her own bad luck**.

Comment: Ahh different scenario. "But [Fortune/Lady Luck/the gods] have always been [unkind, mean, nasty, unfair} to me" would be typical phrases. Or, ironically, "I see that luck has smiled on me in her typical way."

Comment: You have to be really careful with "tough luck" - intonation and context is everything.  It can be almost as rude as "fuck you" depending on how you say it.  I'd suggest ESL speakers avoid it until they're very comfortable with the ways it can be interpreted.  In the wrong way it's not sympathetic at all - quite the opposite, trivializing the person's predicament and expressing complete disinterest in their problems and a total disinclination to help.

Answer (score 0):

"That is the story of my life!" [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/story_of_my_life)

You can take this from fairly mild, "The bus pulled out just as I got there--story of my life!" to extreme depending on tone of voice, context, and adding in swearing to taste. ("The bus pulled out just as I got there, and ran over my bicycle on the way--story of my fucking life!")

With enough context and the right tone of voice, you can just say "typical" or "that's typical" (or even "that's sooooo typical!"). For example, if you have someone running up to the bus waving and the bus pulling away, they could just say "Typical!" (I can't figure out what part of speech this is or find a good reference, but it's common usage. Maybe someone else can add a reference here.)